# Jquery plugin for widget to scroll number up and down?

Tags: android, jquery, user-interface, widget

I'm looking for something that behaves like a text box and a drop-down for numbers. It has "up" and "down" buttons on the side. Clicking or holding "up" increases the number on the text box. Clicking or holding "down" button decreases it.

I remember seeing it in Visual Basic forms but I'm wondering if there is a web equivalent of such a thing; in the form of a jquery plugin or something.

I need it to look something like this.

[image]

Bonus points: If I could click on the "up" arrow and drag it upwards, the number should increment faster and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the widget is apparently "numeric textbox". [Kendo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index) has a numeric textbox widget that gives this exact behavior, but it's not free.

I found another free widget called [jstepper](http://jstepper.emkay.dk/), but it's probably buggy and doesn't provide the behavior I'm expecting.

Comment: Kendo UI Core is free and open source which include NumericTextbox widget http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison